# Cant send data ajax in laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel

I m trying to login this from with ajax but ajax dont work :( can you help me

My Controller

```
 public function login(Request $request)
{

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'password' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email',
    ]);

    if ($validator->passes()) {
        if (auth()->attempt(array('email' => $request->input('email'),
            'password' => $request->input('password')),true))
        {
            return response()->json(["status" => true]);
        }
        return response()->json(['error'=>false]);
    }

    return response()->json(['error'=>$validator->errors()]);
}
```

my View

```
<div id="giris-yap" class="ekran" x-show="tab === 'giris-yap'">

<form action="javascript:void(0)" id="loginform" action="{{ route('giris') }}" method="post">
    @csrf
    <div class="form-group">

        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="E-Posta"
               @error('email') style="border-color:red" @enderror>
        <label class="lab" for="email">E-Posta</label>
        <small style="color: red;" id="email" class="text-danger error-text email_err hata"></small>
    </div>

    <div class="password-input form-group">

        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Şifre"
               @error('password') style="border-color:red" @enderror>
        <label class="lab" for="password">Şifre</label>
        <span toggle="#password" class="fa fa-fw fa-eye field-icon toggle-password"></span>
        <small style="color: red;" id="password" class="text-danger error-text password_err hata"></small>
    </div>

    <div class="remember col-2 gap-10">
        <div class="form-check">
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Beni Hatırla</label>
        </div>
        <span class="password-request">
    <a href="/forgot-password" title="">Şifremi Unuttum</a>
</span>
    </div>

    <small id="mydiv" style="color: red; margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 10px; display: none  "  class="text-danger password_err">Lütfen Eposta ve Şifrenizi Kontrol edin.</small>


    <button type="submit" class="btn loginBtn">Giriş Yap</button>

</form>
```

my ajax

```
<script>
    //login ajax
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#loginform").submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            var email = $("#email").val();
            var password = $("#password").val();

            $.ajax({
                url: "{{ route('giris') }}",
                type:'POST',
                data:{'_token' : '{{ csrf_token() }}', email:email, password:password},
                success: function(data) {
                    printMsg(data)

                    if(data.status === true)
                    {
                        console.log(data.status)
                        window.location.href = '/';
                    }
                    if(data.error === true){
                    console.log(data.error)
                        $('#mydiv').show()

                    }
                },

            });

        });

        function printMsg (msg) {
            if($.isEmptyObject(msg.error)){
            }else{
                $.each( msg.error, function( key, value ) {
                    $('.'+key+'_err').text(value);
                });
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by, "ajax dont work"? Is it the the ajax request isn't getting performed? You're getting an error? You not getting an error but you're meant to?

Comment: You have to change this line `<form action="javascript:void(0)" id="loginform" action="{{ route('giris') }}" method="post">`

Answer (score 0):

do not pass route  just pass in form open tag @csrf and on button Sign In and then
in js script like this. function login(){  $.ajaxSetup({
headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')}});
$.ajax({ type : 'POST',  url: '{{route('login.check')}}', data : data,success : function(response) {console.log(response); if(response == 1) {
window.location.replace('{{route('test.index')}}');  }else if(response == 3)
{ $("#err").hide().html("Username or Password  Incorrect. PleaseCheck").fadeIn('slow'); }  } });}